# CKEditor onSubmit doesn't work after text is entered in the control

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor

So I have installed ckeditor on my project. The control loads fine and you are able to view it. The error occurs when you type something in the textarea. The 'Next' button doesn't work. If there is no text in the textarea the 'Next' button works just fine. When there is text and you press the 'Next' button, I am also noticing these errors in the browser.

EDIT: Please note that the View here is a **Partial View**.

[image: Error in Browser]

I am using **ckeditor 3.6.4**. I installed it using **Nuget**. I have the proper files that came with it.

In my _Shared/Layout Files I include the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js")"></script>
```

In my View  I have the following:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController", new { id = Model.Id}, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "dynamicData", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
        {
            <div class="grid_6">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.SomeText, new { @class = "someTextArea" })
            </div>

            <div class="grid_6 alpha omega">
                <input type="submit" value="Next" class="grid_6 alpha omega button drop_4 gravity_5" />
            </div>
        }
```

and in my javascript I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        ReBindCKEditor();
    });

    function BindCKEditor() {
        var elem = $('#SomeText');
        elem.ckeditor(function () { }, { toolbar: [
        ['Source'],
        ['Preview'],
        ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Scayt'],
        ['Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', 'RemoveFormat'],
        ['Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule'],
        ['Styles', 'Format'],
        ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Strike'],
        ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', 'Blockquote'],
        ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']
        ]
        });
    }

    function ReBindCKEditor() {
        delete CKEDITOR.instances['SomeText'];
        BindCKEditor();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before submitting you need to update the hidden text fields ckeditor uses.  This can be done with

```
for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
```

Say you wrap this in a javascript function called `BeforeSubmittingCKEditor` to follow your naming above, then you could add to your BeginForm the following hook

```
OnBegin = "BeforeSubmittingCKEditor"
```

so your AjaxOptions would look something like this:

```
new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", 
                  UpdateTargetId = "dynamicData", 
                  InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                  OnBegin = "BeforeSubmittingCKEditor" }
```

Comment: I tried this but no luck. Same issue! Doesn't proceed if I place text in the control.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably (it is hard to be 100% sure without further details on the error - the actual content of the error response would help) you are hitting **"A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client"** issue here. By default, the ASP.NET MVC framework checks requests during model binding to determine whether they contain potentially dangerous content as HTML markup. If HTML is detected, model binding throws an error.

There are two ways out of this for you. First approach it to use `AllowHtmlAttribute` in your model class on the server side:

```
...
[AllowHtml]
public string SomeText { get; set; }
...
```

Second way is to enable client side output encoding in the *CKEditor* with `htmlEncodeOutput` option:

```
function BindCKEditor() {
    var elem = $('#SomeText');
    elem.ckeditor(function () { }, {
        htmlEncodeOutput: true,
        toolbar: [
            ['Source'],
            ['Preview'],
            ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Scayt'],
            ['Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll', 'RemoveFormat'],
            ['Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule'],
            ['Styles', 'Format'],
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Strike'],
            ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', 'Blockquote'],
            ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']
        ]
    });
}
```

For more detailed analysis we would need to see entire error message.

Comment: I tried this as well as @dove had suggested, but it doesn't' work.

Comment: @jmogera Can you provide a full content of error response (for exampel from FireBug or Fiddler - with firendly errors disabled of course)?

Comment: User error. This is working. Combination of your code and @dove